# How to add a toc to the upper of each Beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I use a `Beamer` template I found here for presentations and it's very nice to see, but I would like to have a table of contents in the upper of each frame as for some `beamer` templates such as `Warsaw`. How could I do that ? This is my mwe :

```
% compile with lualatex or xelatex:
\documentclass[svgnames, 14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox,fontspec,microtype,ragged2e}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts,serif,structuresmallcapsserif}
 \setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,SmallCapsFeatures={Kerning=Uppercase}]{Minion Pro}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}    
 \usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
 \linespread{1.0344}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{caption}
 \usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
 \beamertemplatesolidbackgroundcolor{Snow}
 \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
 \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
 \apptocmd{\frame}{\justifying}{}{}  
 \addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{}{\justifying}
 \definecolor{alert}{HTML}{347941}
  \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=alert}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent=2}
 \title{My title}
 \author{My name}
 \institute{My institution}
 \date{}
 \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

 \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split` outer theme, with `\useoutertheme` in your preamble:

```
\useoutertheme{split}
```

This outer theme will add a header bar, split in two parts: on the left, this list of sections is shown, with the current section highlighted; on the right, le list of subsections of the current section is shown, with the current subsection highlighted.
This will also add a footer bar with the author name and the presentation title, which you can remove by adding to your preamble:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
```

As you asked how to left-align the section list, you can do it by adding the following to your preamble:

```
\usesectionheadtemplate{\insertsectionhead\hfill}{\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead\hfill}
```

You can also try the `tree` outer theme, which shows the current section and subsection in a tree structure.

Comment: Thanks so much ! Is there a way to move the header toc to the left or to the right ?

Comment: Is it possible to add subsections to the toc ?

Comment: @domi Please read my update, I detailed a bit what you are supposed to get (Warsaw-style table of content). If I understand what you want, you are better off with the `tree` outer theme.